# Impossible to run Cucumber file

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, cucumber, bdd

I cannot run Cucumber feature file. When I move the pointer to the green arrows at the left side Intelij says: "Nothing here". Also there is no option to run the file after clicking right mouse button. I saw guys in YouTube had "Cucumber Java" option at Run Configurations, but I don't, although have this dependency and Gherkin plugin installed. Also Intelij don't provides any suggestions to solve "Undefined step reference" warning. How can I solve this problem?

My maven dependencies:

[image: Maven dependencies]

My run configurations:

[image: Run Configurations]

Comment: Do you use IntelliJ Ultimate or IntelliJ Community?

Comment: IntelliJ Community

Comment: Did you install the plug-ins [as stated here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-cucumber-support-in-project.html)?

Comment: Oh, thanks I installed Cucumber Java plugin and it worked!